# Why c++ singleton cannot new though "new" has been overloded

Tags: c++, singleton, operator-keyword, new-operator

I'm new here, I've learned that the "new" operator can be overloaded and when I call "new" , it will first call "operator new" and then the "constructor", so my question is if I can new object in singleton pattern when I overload new in the public area?

```
class MyClass{
    MyClass(){
        cout<<"contructor"<<endl;
    }

public:
    static MyClass* getInstance()
    {
        static MyClass* mm = new MyClass();
        return mm;
    }
    void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
        cout<<"allocate memory\n";
        void* p = malloc(size);
        return p;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass*  m = new MyClass();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see no need to overload `operator new` in your case. And by allocating dynamically in your `getInstance` function (which you do not call!) you will also have a memory leak.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The normal singleton idiom is to only allocate the object if it is not already allocated.  It is *just* possible that the OP has eliminated that test because it isn't relevant to his question.  (If so, that is *awesome* behaviour from a new poster.)

Comment: A one-off memory leak is (or, may be) harmless.  The reason for dynamic allocation is to avoid the static initialization order fiasco (of course you need mutexes or atomics to do that safely in multi-threaded operation).

Comment: Yeah, I found that,  it's the sample code with singleton pattern and  I'm not focusing on it. In fact, I can free it in the destructor .

Comment: @MartinBonner no need for synchronization since C++11, because the compiler guarantees it. It might be worth mentioning that most problems of SIOF would be more simply be resolved by using a local static instance rather than static pointer to a dynamic instance. Dynamic allocation does resolve one subtle/obscure case related to SIOF. In particular, if *destructor* of a static object depends on this singleton, but it fails to call `getInstance` in its constructor, there would be no guarantee that the destruction happens in the necessary order. Leaking the singleton guarantees that it exists.

Comment: @user2079303 If you may be assigning to the pointer in different threads, you absolutely need synchronization.  If you use a static variable and rely on the static initialization occurring in *one* thread, then the compiler has to provide the synchronization for you.

Comment: @MartinBonner There has to be synchronization, yes. But no, **you** don't need to synchronize the initialisation (since C++11) because, as I said, the compiler is required to do it. If there is only one thread (potentially) doing the initialisation, then there would be no need for synchronization (whether compiler provided or explicit).

Comment: @user2079303 My bad.  I was replying on the basis mm was a static member variable which was assigned to.  In fact it is a block scope static non-member variable which is initialized - which means it gets the C++11 guarantees.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

> when I call `new` , it will first call `operator new`

Yup

> and then the constructor

Or at least it will try to.  The problem is that the constructor is private so a call from outside the class is not allowed.

The call to the constructor is from the scope of the `new` expression (so "from `main`" in your case), not from the scope of `operator new`.

Comment: so the "new" will call the constructor where it is called not in the scope it is defined?

Comment: @CatTom - Exactly so.  Operator new just allocates memory.  It doesn't call the constructor.

Comment: @CatTom `operator new` does not define the `new` in the new-expression. Think of `operator new` as a strange way to spell "allocate". It doesn't work like overloads of actual operators at all.